# Disable a h:commandButton when h:inputText has no value

Tags: javascript, jsf-1.2

I have two h:inputText textboxes and a h:commandButton. How can i disable the button in case there is no value in either of the text box? Also how do i disable the other text box in case i have value in one of the text box. Please find my sample code below:

```
<h:form id="myForm">    
    <h:inputText id="first" value=#{myBean.first}></h:inputText>
    <h:inputText id="second" value=#{myBean.second}></h:inputText>
    <h:commandButton id="submit" action="#{myBean.submit}" value="Submit"/>
</h:form>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("myForm:first").onkeyup = function() {
    if (this.value.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("myForm:second").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("myForm:submit").disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myForm:second").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("myForm:submit").disabled = true;
    }
};
document.getElementById("myForm:second").onkeyup = function() {
    if (this.value.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("myForm:first").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("myForm:submit").disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myForm:first").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("myForm:submit").disabled = true;
    }
};
```

The problem here is it works fine, but i have to click outside once to enable/disable the button. Is there anyway the button gets enabled automatically and the other text box gets disabled the moment a data is entered into one of the text boxes?

Comment: Could you post the generated HTML for myForm?

Answer (score 0):

onload or directly in commandButton tag  keep the button as 
        `disabled="true"`.
 Implement the onchange or onblur method to inpuText and set the style to the commandButton disable='false'

Answer (score -1):

use onchange event instead of keyup